# Changes in array of coprime numbers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

I'm given an array and have to determine the minimum number of additions(ADDITION BY 1) that have to be done to the elements such that they are all no longer coprime(GCD>1)
I could recursively check if the gcd is >1. If it is not, I thought that the easiest GCD to get would be 2, so I can add 1 to all the odd numbers and get the GCD as 2 however this fails for cases with very few/no even numbers and where it is easier to generate other GCDs such as 11, 33, 55 and 76. Here I can add 1 to 76 and change the GCD from 1 to 11 in 1 step rather than changing 11,33 and 55 by making 3 additions and getting GCD as 2. 
I wanted to know the most efficient way of doing this. Also checking the GCD of the array would be O(nlogn).

Comment: Does this problem come from a coding competition/challenge (online or other...)?

Comment: Not that I can think of. I was solving some problems on GCD and learning about prime factors, eulers totient function etc when I stumbled upon this on the ebook I was reading some days ago. I thought of this for a while, but I couldn't come up with a solution at all, which is why I asked.

Comment: And you're *sure* you're meant to minimize the sum of added values?

Comment: At first I would want to find just the approach to ensure that they are all not coprime, the minimising would come at the end. If I don't want to minimise them, wouldn't just converting them all to even numbers work? That was the first thing I thought of and then developed these cases like I mentioned where there can be a better way of doing that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there was no attempt made to solve this problem and OP is asking someone to solve an online programming puzzle for him.

Comment: It looks like it's coming from https://www.codechef.com/JAN16/problems/CBALLS

Answer (score 1):

You could find the prime factorization of each element, then count how many elements have each prime in the factorization. The number of additions required is *[Element count] - [MAX(Prime Count)]*.

For example, the factorization for [11, 33, 55, 76] is:

> 11: 11^1
>    33: 3^1 * 11^1
>    55: 5^1 * 11^1
>    76: 2^2 * 19^1

The prime counts are:

> 2: 1
>    3: 1
>    5:1
>    11: 3
>    19: 1

The highest count is 3, there are 4 elements, so you need 1 addition (4 - 3). If you need to know which elements need to be added to, it's the elements whose factorization *don't* include the max counted prime.

Comment: I didn't quite understand that, could you perhaps show with an example?

Comment: For each prime factor, count how many times it's occurring in the array.
On your example: 11 appears 3 times (that's the max), so the answer is 4-3 = 1.

Comment: For the example
11 13 15
This gives the answer as 2, but it actually is 3.
Also what is the logic behind this?

Comment: Just to clarify, the additions meant adding 1. That is 1 step.